# Will different threads end at the same time as the first one to finish?

Tags: python, multithreading

I'm new to thread in python, i have a question that, supposed i start 3 threads like below, each one takes care of 1 different task:

```
def start( taskName, delay):
   // do somthing with each taskName

# Create two threads as follows
try:
   thread.start_new_thread( start, ("task1", ) )
   thread.start_new_thread( start, ("task2", ) )
   thread.start_new_thread( start, ("task3", ) )
except:
   print "Error: unable to start thread"
```

Supposed that for each "start", it takes around 10-15 seconds to finish depending on each taskName it is. My question is that, if task 1 finishes in 12 seconds, tasks 2 in 10secs and task 3 in 15 seconds. Will task 2 finish then close and leave task 1 and task 3 to run till finish, or will task 2 force task 1 and 3 to close after task 2 is finished?

Are there any arguments that we can pass to the start_new_thread method in order to archive 2 of the things that I have mentioned above:
1. First to finish forces the rest to close.
2. Each one finish individually.

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Max Noel already mentioned, it is advised to use the Thread class instead of using start_new_thread.

Now, as for your two questions:

**1. First to finish forces the rest to close**
You will need two important things: a shared queue that the threads can put their ID in once they are done. And a shared Event that will signal all threads to stop working when it is triggered. The main thread will wait for the first thread to put something in the queue and will then trigger the event to stop all threads.

```
import threading
import random
import time
import Queue

def work(worker_queue, id, stop_event):
    while not stop_event.is_set():
        print "This is worker", id

        # do stuff
        time.sleep(random.random() * 5)

        # put worker ID in queue
        if not stop_event.is_set():
            worker_queue.put(id)

        break

# queue for workers
worker_queue = Queue.Queue()

# indicator for other threads to stop
stop_event = threading.Event()

# run workers
threads = []
threads.append(threading.Thread(target=work, args=(worker_queue, 0, stop_event)))
threads.append(threading.Thread(target=work, args=(worker_queue, 1, stop_event)))
threads.append(threading.Thread(target=work, args=(worker_queue, 2, stop_event)))

for thread in threads:
    thread.start()

# this will block until the first element is in the queue
first_finished = worker_queue.get()

print first_finished, 'was first!'

# signal the rest to stop working
stop_event.set()
```

**2. Each finish individually**
Now this is much easier. Just call the `join` method on all Thread objects. This will wait for each thread to finish.

```
for thread in threads:
    thread.start()

for thread in threads:
    thread.join()
```

Btw, the above code is for Python 2.7. Let me know if you need Python 3

Comment: very informative and applicable for what im working on, thank you. For your answer for number 2, do I need to call thread.start()? what's the difference between start and join?

Comment: Start will start the thread. Join will wait for the thread to finish - it will not start it

Comment: so for 2/ inside the loop we must have both join() and start() in order for it to work, is it correct?

Comment: Oh okay I see. Sorry, the second code might be a little bit too short. I was assuming that you first started all threads like in section 1. I will edit my answer later. So you first start all threads (for example in a loop) and then you join them all. Sorry for the confusion

Answer (score 1):

First off, don't use `start_new_thread`, it's a low-level primitive. Use the `Thread` class in the `threading` module instead.

Once you have that, `Thread` instances have a `.join()` method, which you can call from another thread (your program's main thread) to wait for them to terminate.

```
t1 = Thread(target=my_func)
t1.start()
# Waits for t1 to finish.
t1.join()
```

Answer (score 0):

All threads will terminate when the process terminates.
Thus, if your main program ends after the `try..except`, then all three threads may get terminated prematurely. For example:

```
import thread
import logging
import time
logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)

def start(taskname, n):
    for i in range(n):
        logger.info('{}'.format(i))
        time.sleep(0.1)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    logging.basicConfig(level=logging.DEBUG,
                        format='[%(asctime)s %(threadName)s] %(message)s',
                        datefmt='%H:%M:%S')
    try:
        thread.start_new_thread( start, ("task1", 10) )
        thread.start_new_thread( start, ("task2", 5) )
        thread.start_new_thread( start, ("task3", 8) )
    except Exception as err:
        logger.exception(err)
```

may print something like

```
[14:15:16 Dummy-3] 0
[14:15:16 Dummy-1] 0
```

In contrast, if you place

```
time.sleep(5)
```

at the end of the script, then you see the full expected output from all three
threads.

---

Note also that the thread module is a low-level module; unless you have a
particular reason for using it, most often people use the threading module which
implements more useful features for dealing with threads, such as a `join`
method which blocks until the thread has finished. See below for an example.

---

[The docs state](https://docs.python.org/2/library/thread.html#thread.start_new_thread):

> When the function returns, the thread silently exits. 
>   When the function terminates with an unhandled exception, a stack trace is
>   printed and then the thread exits (**but other threads continue to run**).

Thus, by default, when one thread finishes, the others continue to run.
The example above also demonstrates this.

---

To make all the threads exit when one function finishes is more difficult.
One thread can not kill another thread cleanly (e.g., without killing the entire
process.)

Using `threading`, you could arrange for the threads to set a variable
(e.g. `flag`) to True when finished, and have each thread check the state of
`flag` periodically and quit if it is True. But note that the other threads will
not necessarily terminate *immediately*; they will only terminate when they next
check the state of `flag`. If a thread is blocked, waiting for I/O for instance,
then it may not check the `flag` for a considerable amount of time (if ever!).

However, if the thread spends most of its time in a quick loop, you could check the state of `flag` once per iteration:

```
import threading
import logging
import time
logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)

def start(taskname, n):
    global flag
    for i in range(n):
        if flag:
            break
        logger.info('{}'.format(i))
        time.sleep(0.1)
    else:
        # get here if loop finishes without breaking
        logger.info('FINISHED')
    flag = True

if __name__ == '__main__':
    logging.basicConfig(level=logging.DEBUG,
                        format='[%(asctime)s %(threadName)s] %(message)s',
                        datefmt='%H:%M:%S')
    threads = list()
    flag = False
    try:
        threads.append(threading.Thread(target=start, args=("task1", 10) ))
        threads.append(threading.Thread(target=start, args=("task2", 5) ))
        threads.append(threading.Thread(target=start, args=("task3", 8) ))
    except Exception as err:
        logger.exception(err)

    for t in threads:
        t.start()
    for t in threads:
        # make the main process wait until all threads have finished.
        t.join()
```